# scala lazy parallel collection (is possible?)

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, stream

is there any way to run a stream in parallel in scala without loading all objects into memory?

note: using par method, will load all objects into memory

```
val list = "a"::"b"::"c"::"d"::"e"::Nil //> list: List[String] = List(a, b, c, d, e)

val s = list.toStream  //> s: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[String] = Stream(a, ?)
val sq = s.par         //> sq: scala.collection.parallel.immutable.ParSeq[String] = ParVector(a, b, c, d, e)
sq.map { x => println("Map 1 "+x);x }
  .map { x => println("Map 2 "+x);x}
  .map { x => println("Map 3 "+x);x }
  .foreach { x => println("done "+x)}
```

Comment: Sounds impossible: "Other collections, such as lists, queues or streams, are inherently sequential in the sense that the elements must be accessed one after the other. These collections are converted to their parallel variants by _copying the elements_ into a similar parallel collection" from http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/conversions.html

Comment: Your question is fairly vague. I have put an answer below which I think answers the question as asked, but I suspect you have a more specific use case in mind. You might get better answers if you ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 4):

In general, yes, this is possible.

As Tzach Zohar commented, the ".par" operator will eagerly load all the elements of the Stream because "streams are inherently sequential in the sense that the elements must be accessed one after the other" (see [the docs](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/conversions.html))

So you can't use the built-in parallel collections for this, but you can still process a stream in parallel using `ExecutionContext` directly, e.g.:

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val infStream = Stream.from(1)

val mappedInfStream = infStream
  .map { x => Future(println(s"processing $x on ${Thread.currentThread.getName}")) }

Await.result(
  Future.sequence(mappedInfStream.take(100)),
  Duration.Inf)
```